# C++ method pointer array

Tags: arrays, pointers, c++11, methods

I have a class which has several methods. Now I would like to have this class have an array of method pointers which can be called with an instance of the class.

Basically like this

```
class MyClass
{
public:
    MyClass(int aInit);

    typedef int (MyClass::*myPtr)(int);
    const myPtr ptrArray[2];
    const myPtr ptrSingle;

    int plus(int b);
    int minus(int b);

private:
    int a;
};
```

With an implementation like the following:

```
MyClass::MyClass(int aInit) :
    ptrArray({&MyClass::plus, &MyClass::minus}),
    ptrSingle(&MyClass::plus)
{
    this->a = aInit;
}

int MyClass::plus(int b)
{
    return (this->a + b);
}

int MyClass::minus(int b)
{
    return (this->a - b);
}
```

From an other class, I have this method using MyClass in which I try to access the function pointer members:

```
MyClass myInstance(10);
MyClass::myPtr function = myInstance.ptrSingle;
int ret1 = function(1);
int ret2 = myInstance.ptrArray[0](1);
int ret3 = myInstance.ptrArray[1](1);
```

This leads to the folliwing error messages:

```
error: must use '.*' or '->*' to call pointer-to-member function in 'function (...)', e.g. '(... ->* function) (...)'
     int ret1 = function(1);
                          ^
error: must use '.*' or '->*' to call pointer-to-member function in 'myInstance.MyClass::ptrArray[0] (...)', e.g. '(... ->* myInstance.MyClass::ptrArray[0]) (...)'
     int ret2 = *(myInstance.ptrArray[0])(1);
                                           ^
error: must use '.*' or '->*' to call pointer-to-member function in 'myInstance.MyClass::ptrArray[1] (...)', e.g. '(... ->* myInstance.MyClass::ptrArray[1]) (...)'
     int ret3 = myInstance.ptrArray[1](1);
                                        ^
```

1. I don't know where to put the *, and I also don't know why a dereference is necessary here. With C, as far as I remember, this should not be necessary when calling a function pointer. 
   I have read that it should be something like `(this->*temp.set_func)(value);` but how can I adapt this syntax to my problem? myInstance is not a member of the class, so I have no `this`. Also, myInstance is not a pointer, so I don't see why * should be necessary. Can anybody help me with this?

   When I initialize the myPtr like this `const myPtr ptrArray[] = {&MyClass::plus, &MyClass::minus};`, the compiler complains `too many initializers for 'int (MyClass::* const [0])(int)'`. But shouldn't be such initializations for non int types be possible with c++11?

I am using gcc (Gentoo 4.9.3 p1.0, pie-0.6.2) 4.9.3 with c++11.

Comment: Those pointers-to-members are not tied to a particular instance of the class. If you have `MyClass a, b;` you'll find that `a.ptrSingle == b.ptrSingle`. So when you want to call a member through such a pointer, you still need to supply an object on which to call it: `(myInstance.*function)(1)`

Comment: `With C, as far as I remember, this should not be necessary when calling a function pointer.` In C++ it is not necessary either. But you aren't working with a plain function pointer - you are working with a pointer to member function. I imagine you don't find it surprising that you can't just call `plus(1)` but have to write `myInstance,plus(1)` - in order to call a non-static member function, you need to supply an object on which to call it. This is equally true whether you refer the member directly by name, or indirectly via a pointer.

Comment: `myInstance is not a pointer, so I don't see why * should be necessary` There is no `*` in that expression. `.*` is a single operator, not "a period followed by a star", just like `>>` is a single operator and not "two greater-then operators in a row". Same for `->*` - it's a single indivisible token.

Comment: For #2, clang gives a better error message: `error: array bound cannot be deduced from an in-class initializer`. You just need to specify the array bound explicitly, as in `const myPtr ptrArray[2] = {&MyClass::plus, &MyClass::minus};`

Comment: Thanks for all your comments. Good to know, that it is simply not possible to leave out the array size. But with `int ret1 = (myInstance.*ptrSingle)(1);` I just get a different error message: `'ptrSingle' was not declared in this scope` @Igor Tandetnik

Comment: (Any idea how this @-thing works?) I think I misunderstood your comment. Of course this works if I do `(myInstance.*function)(1)`. Thank you! I will post a solution to this soon.

Comment: That would be `(myInstance.*myInstance.ptrSingle)(1)`

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Igor Tandetnik from the comment section, I can now post an answer to question 1:

```
MyClass myInstance(10);
MyClass::myPtr function = myInstance.ptrSingle;
MyClass::myPtr functionFromArray = myInstance.ptrArray[1];

int ret1 = (myInstance.*function)(1);
int ret2 = (myInstance.*(myInstance.ptrArray[0]))(1);
int ret3 = (myInstance.*(myInstance.ptrArray[1]))(1);
int ret4 = (myInstance.*functionFromArray)(1);
```

My mistake was to assume that the method pointer directly points to the method of an instance. Ans since the lines with ret2 and 3 look really ugly, I have added an example on how to access the array. Maybe this is useful for somebody else!